# problem when start django with gunicorn, how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I tried running my project using Gunicorn with the command `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`, but the result was an error and gunicorn cancelled the boot.

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core.wsgi:application
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8560] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8560] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (8560)
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8560] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8565] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8565
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8565] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker                                                                                                        
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process                                                                                                   
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi                                                                                                      
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp                                                                                                     
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/core/core/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = WSGIHandler()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__                                                                                                   
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in load_middleware                                                                                             
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string                                                                                             
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                                
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                                  
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                                    
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>                                                                                                
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__                                                                                                        
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config                                                                                       
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/rofi/demo.protek/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready                                                                                                
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8565] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8565)
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8560] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-03-26 10:55:16 +0000] [8560] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

What's wrong about it? Any help to fix it?

Comment: are you able to run the development server?

Comment: add `import django;django.setup()` code at the top of `/home/rofi/demo.protek/core/core/wsgi.py` file

Comment: Could you please share your `settings.py` file and what you gave to the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: in my setting.py `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'`

Answer (score 0):

Devang Padhiyar thanks for your answer. let see my setting.py file

```
import os
import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta
import time
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf.locale.en import formats as es_formats
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from easy_thumbnails.conf import Settings as thumbnail_settings
from django.core.files import File as FileWrapper
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import Http404
from django.contrib.messages import constants as message_constants

from core import get_shortcut, get_shortcut_setting


MESSAGE_LEVEL = message_constants.DEBUG
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = '%h_=n$2yh554=2za0zsb%ubk!tg=e0)l@_w@ap#^d#_ew7)yig'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', '103.105.98.214', 'protek.id', 'demo.protek.id', 'localhost']
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'grappelli.dashboard',
    'admin_shortcuts',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'grappelli',
    'django_admin_env_notice',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'grappelli_autocomplete_fk_edit_link',
    'el_pagination',
    'crispy_forms', # http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
    'django_select2', # https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2
    'easy_select2',
    'easy_thumbnails', # https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails
    'image_cropping',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_admin_caching',
    'user_sessions', # app/user_sessions/session/
    'nested_admin', # inline multiple tree
    'tabbed_admin', # tabbed jquery
    'watchman', # monitor status database IPADDRESS/watchman/
    'django.contrib.humanize', # Money formated for HTML
    'mptt', # Tree
    'sorl.thumbnail',  # http://django-file-picker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
    'clear_cache', # python manage.py clear_cache
    'cachetable', # database Cache /app/sysconf/cachetable/
    'ckeditor', # editor
    'dbbackup_ui', # Bakcup Db dan media | app/backups/backup-database-and-media/
    'session_security', # http://django-session-security.readthedocs.io | Ipaddress/session_security/ping/
    'reversion', # VersionAdmin data model
    'reversion_compare', # https://github.com/jedie/django-reversion-compare
    'debug_toolbar', # https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io
    'djangobower', # Pendukung debug toolbar | https://axiacore.com/blog/effective-dependency-management-django-using-bower/
    # 'export_action', # Download exel disetiap table model
    'import_export', # http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io
    'tagging',
    'smart_selects', # Berhubungan dengan popup, get dll
    'bidiutils', # Context processor
    'pipeline', # https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    'django_postgrespool', # Postgres Connection Pooling backend
    'djangosecure',
    'treewidget',
    # 'sysconf',
    # 'moderation',  # or 'moderation.apps.ModerationConfig',,
    'django_pg_current_timestamp',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'robots', # https://godjango.com/23-robots-and-sitemaps/
    'filer', # https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    'autofixture', # https://pypi.org/project/django-autofixture/
    'corsheaders', # https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/
    'django_nose',
    'redisboard',
    'core_doc',
    'crm_mstdata',
    'globalmasters',
    'hris',
    'hris_mstdata',
    'crm',
    'homepage',
    'product',
    # 'placement',
    'facultative',
    'finance',
    'docman',
    'treaty',
]
# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================






# BACKEND SETUP =========================================================================
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'session_security.middleware.SessionSecurityMiddleware',
    'x_forwarded_for.middleware.XForwardedForMiddleware',
    'qinspect.middleware.QueryInspectMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'user_sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"
ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
]

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    # 'loggers': {
    #     'django.db.backends': {
    #         'level': 'DEBUG',
    #         'handlers': ['console'],
    #     },
    #     'qinspect': {
    #         'handlers': ['console'],
    #         'level': 'DEBUG',
    #         'propagate': True,
    #     }
    # },
}

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'cachetable',
    },
}

# CACHES = {
#     "default": {
#         "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
#         "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
#         "OPTIONS": {
#             "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
#         },
#         "KEY_PREFIX": "brokr"
#     },
#     'select2': {
#         "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
#         "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/2",
#         "OPTIONS": {
#             "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
#         }
#     }
# }

# SELECT2_CACHE_BACKEND = 'select2'

CACHE_TTL = 60 * 15


SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 30 * 60 # 30 Menit
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

COMPRESS = True
COMPRESS_AUTO = True
COMPRESS_VERSION = True
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None

# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================


# FRONT END SETUP =========================================================================
THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters',
    'image_cropping.thumbnail_processors.crop_corners',
) + thumbnail_settings.THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS

THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '': {
        'avatar': {'size': (50, 50), 'crop': True},
    },
}
THUMBNAIL_HIGH_RESOLUTION = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'bidiutils.context_processors.bidi',
                'django_admin_env_notice.context_processors.from_settings',
                # 'context_processors.app_list',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                    'apptemplates.Loader',
                ]),
            ],

        },
    },
]

DYNAMIC_PREFERENCES = {
    'MANAGER_ATTRIBUTE': 'preferences',
    'REGISTRY_MODULE': 'dynamic_preferences_registry',
    'ADMIN_ENABLE_CHANGELIST_FORM': False,
    'SECTION_KEY_SEPARATOR': '__',
    'ENABLE_CACHE': True,
    'VALIDATE_NAMES': True,
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
    # 'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)

BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = '/PROJECT_ROOT/assets/bower_components/'

BOWER_PATH = '/usr/bin/bower'

BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'markitup#1.1.14',
    'mediaelement#2.22.0',
    'blueimp-file-upload#9.12.5',
)

PIPELINE = {
    'PIPELINE_ENABLED': True,
    'JS_COMPRESSOR': 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor',
    'CSS_COMPRESSOR': 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor',
}

JS_WRAPPER = "(function(){stuff();%s})();"

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono-lisa',
        'toolbar': [["Format", "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "SpellChecker", "Print"],
                   ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', "Indent", "Outdent", 'JustifyLeft', 
                     'JustifyCenter','JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
                   ["Image", "Table", "Link", "Unlink", "Anchor", "SectionLink", 
                    "Subscript", "Superscript"], ['Undo', 'Redo'], ["Source"],
                   ["Maximize"]],
        'tabSpaces': 3,
        'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        'width': 880,
        },

}

CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = False
# TABBED_ADMIN_USE_JQUERY_UI = True
# TABBED_ADMIN_JQUERY_UI_CSS = 'tabbed_admin/css/tabbed_grappelli_admin.css'
# TABBED_ADMIN_JQUERY_UI_JS = 'tabbed_admin/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

UPLOADFILE = '/files/'

STATIC_DEPS = True

# TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True
DEFAULT_FILER_SERVERS = {
    'private': {
        'main': {
            'ENGINE': 'filer.server.backends.default.DefaultServer',
        },
        'thumbnails': {
            'ENGINE': 'filer.server.backends.default.DefaultServer',
        }
    }
}


# =====================================================================================
# =====================================================================================




# DATABASE SETUP ======================================================================
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'core',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Kambing1',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60 * 10, # 10 minutes
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    }
}

SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
    'default': 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2'
}

DATABASE_POOL_ARGS = {
    'max_overflow': 10,
    'pool_size': 5,
    'recycle': 300
}
# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================


# OTHER SETUP
VARNISH_MANAGEMENT_ADDRS = ('127.0.0.1:6082',)
es_formats.DATETIME_FORMAT = "Y-m-d H:i:s"
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_BIDI = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Jakarta'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
SITE_ID = 1
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'AIzaSyD8BxyAFUwWxv2lUnFv06ekTakzTr3sl-E'
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '316233965812-sjbuqlsaat19vesjo6fa44jrlidjit7d.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'ff-pKw85dbNjYxydjM5FTRxz'

# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================





# SECURTY UPDATE ========================================================================
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER      = False
HOST_SCHEME                     = "http://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER         = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT             = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE           = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE              = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS             = None
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  = False
SECURE_FRAME_DENY               = False
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER       = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF     = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD             = True

# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================






# EMAIL SETUP =============================================================================
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_multiple_email_backends.backend.CombinedEmailBackend'
EMAIL_BACKEND_LIST = ['django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend',
                      'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend']
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "sent_emails")
EMAIL_HOST      = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'jasawarung@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'cgkxqhzuyfatucor'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

CONTACT_US_EMAIL = 'jasawarung@gmail.com'

# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================


# DEBUG TOOLBAR ===========================================================================
def show_toolbar(request):
    return True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK" : show_toolbar,
    'DISABLE_PANELS': {
        'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    },
}

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
]

CONFIG_DEFAULTS = {
    'RESULTS_CACHE_SIZE': 3,
    'SHOW_COLLAPSED': True,
    'SQL_WARNING_THRESHOLD': 100,   # milliseconds
}
# =========================================================================================
# =========================================================================================


# THEME SETUP ============================================================================
GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'core.dashboard.GlobalSetting'
GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = 'BROKR PLATFORM'
GRAPPELLI_AUTOCOMPLETE_LIMIT = 20
GRAPPELLI_CLEAN_INPUT_TYPES =  True
GRAPPELLI_SWITCH_USER = False
GRAPPELLI_SWITCH_USER_ORIGINAL =  True
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 3600  # 1 hour
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True

def itemDate():
    return datetime.date.today()

ADMIN_SHORTCUTS = [
    {   
        'title': 'Date Now : ' + str(itemDate()),
        'shortcuts': [
            {
                'title': 'Home',
                'url': '/',
            },
            {
                'title': 'Treaty',
                'url': '/treaty/',
                'icon': 'clipboard',
                # 'count_new': 'core.utils.count_submission',
            },
            {
                'title': 'Facultative',
                'url': '/facultative/',
                'icon': 'paperclip',
                # 'count_new': 'core.utils.count_submission',
            },
            {
                'title': 'CRM',
                'url': '/crm/',
                'icon': 'address-book',
                # 'count_new': 'core.utils.count_account',
            },
            # {
            #     'title': 'Project',
            #     'url': '/placement/',
            #     'icon': 'folder',
                # 'count_new': 'core.utils.count_submission',
            # },
            {
                'title': 'HRD',
                'url': '/hris/',
                'icon': 'users',
                # 'count_new': 'core.utils.count_account',
            },
            {
                'title': 'Financial & Accounting',
                'url': '/finance/',
                'icon': 'chart-pie',
                # 'count_new': 'core.utils.count_account',
            },
            # {
            #     'title': 'Profile',
            #     'url': '/hris/employeesadmin/',
            #     'icon': 'user',
            # },
        ]
    },
]

ADMIN_SHORTCUTS_SETTINGS = {
    'show_on_all_pages': True,
    'hide_app_list': False,
    'open_new_window': False,
}
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'uni_form'
APPEND_SLASH = False

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('pl', 'Polish'),
)

# MARKDOWN_DEUX_STYLES = {
#     "default": {
#         "extras": {
#             "code-friendly": None,
#         },
#         "safe_mode": "escape",
#     },
# }




# ROBOTS SETUP ============================================================================
ROBOTS_USE_SITEMAP = False
ROBOTS_SITEMAP_URLS = [
    'http://103.105.98.211:8001/sitemap.xml',
]
ROBOTS_SITEMAP_VIEW_NAME = 'cached-sitemap'
ROBOTS_USE_HOST = False
ROBOTS_USE_SCHEME_IN_HOST = True
ROBOTS_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 60*60*24

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# EXPLORER_CONNECTIONS = { 'Default': 'default', 'Pws': 'pws' } 
# EXPLORER_DEFAULT_CONNECTION = 'default'
# EXPLORER_TASKS_ENABLED =  True
# EXPLORER_DEFAULT_ROWS = 5000
# EXPLORER_DATA_EXPORTERS = [('csv', 'explorer.exporters.CSVExporter'), ('excel', 'explorer.exporters.ExcelExporter'), ('json', 'explorer.exporters.JSONExporter')]
# EXPLORER_SQL_WHITELIST = ('CREATED', 'UPDATED', 'DELETED','REGEXP_REPLACE')
# EXPLORER_SQL_BLACKLIST = ('ALTER', 'RENAME ', 'DROP', 'TRUNCATE', 'INSERT INTO', 'UPDATE', 'REPLACE', 'DELETE', 'ALTER', 'CREATE TABLE', 'SCHEMA', 'GRANT', 'OWNER TO')
# EXPLORER_UNSAFE_RENDERING = True

# Whether the Query Inspector should do anything (default: False)
QUERY_INSPECT_ENABLED = True
# Whether to log the stats via Django logging (default: True)
QUERY_INSPECT_LOG_STATS = True
# Whether to add stats headers (default: True)
QUERY_INSPECT_HEADER_STATS = True
# Whether to log duplicate queries (default: False)
QUERY_INSPECT_LOG_QUERIES = True
# Whether to log queries that are above an absolute limit (default: None - disabled)
QUERY_INSPECT_ABSOLUTE_LIMIT = 100 # in milliseconds
# Whether to log queries that are more than X standard deviations above the mean query time (default: None - disabled)
QUERY_INSPECT_STANDARD_DEVIATION_LIMIT = 2
# Whether to include tracebacks in the logs (default: False)
QUERY_INSPECT_LOG_TRACEBACKS = True
# Project root (a list of directories, see below - default empty)
# QUERY_INSPECT_TRACEBACK_ROOTS = ['/path/to/my/django/project/']

ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "Production server"
ENVIRONMENT_COLOR = "#FF2222"
ENVIRONMENT_ADMIN_SELECTOR = "grp-header"

REDISBOARD_DETAIL_FILTERS = ['.*']

ADD_REVERSION_ADMIN=True
```

`

Comment: Please add this to your question